# SVM vs decision trees in small datasets with batch effects

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I trained a SVM and a random forest on a biological small data set (binary classification), yielding a solid training performance (ROC of around 0.85 for the 10 times 10-fold CV training). After that I tried to predict an independent test set, which for sure has some batch effects in it. The SVM model worked out quite good for the classification while RF basically failed. I think that SVM did a better job in generalization while RF maybe especially over-learned the characteristics of the batch effects.

I would be interested if there is some (scientific) literature available concerning the robustness of SVM when it comes to the robustness towards batch effects / noise, maybe in comparison to RF. This would help me a lot understanding this phenomenom.

Thanks in advance.